# Problem in the Windows boot screen

Tags: boot

Once i had kept a supervisor password to my windows boot screen, but now i forgot that password, Now i am unable to access the boot menu since its asking the password, all menu options are disabled. Is it possible to remove that password and can i get the boot menu default settings back?
I had tried to change the jumper settings too, but the problem hasn't been solved.

Processor: Intel Pentium dual core (2) OS : XP

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how it's possible to set a password on the boot menu, since this is done at a very early stage in the computer startup process.

In case you're rather referring to the Recovery Console, the password can be effectively deleted by configuring an automatic administrator logon.

See a detailed description in :
[How to enable an administrator to log on automatically in Recovery Console](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312149)

In a nutshell, the procedure is:

1. Go to Start->Run
2. Type `%SystemRoot%\system32\secpol.msc /s`
3. Click Local Policies, then Security Options.
4. Double-click the Recovery Console: `Allow automatic administrative logon` policy, and set it to Enabled.